# how subtract 10 minutes from a timestamp, not the current time

Tags: linux, bash, date, time, expr

If I have a variable like 2005, that represents an hour and minute, in this case 08:05pm. How do I subtract 15 minutes from that.  If you use expr, you do get something like 1990, which isn't a time.  expr works if you are subtracting less than the remaining of the hour, like 2040-15=2025. but that wont work every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using gnu `date`:

```
n='2005'
date -d "$n 15 min ago" '+%H%M'

1950
```

Comment: It did.  This was my first question to this forum, so I didnt see how to reply until just now.  Thanks alot.

Comment: It does what I asked, but I decided that what I was asking for is only half what what I need. i am stuck on the second part of the same problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to post a new question if are stuck on it for long time